# Rank of a matrix factor when product is zero

Tags: linear-algebra

Can someone give me a way to start this problem please?

Suppose $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $n\times p$
matrix with the property that $AB=0$. Determine the maximum value
that the rank of $B$ can take in terms of the rank of $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: What can you say about the image (or column space) of $B$ and the kernel (or nullspace) of $A$?

Comment: $Img(B) \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ $ker(A)=B$ right?

Comment: @Mark: I don't understand what you've typed here. But, true, the image of $B$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$.

Comment: I'm kinda lost, so could you elaborate more on your hint please?

Comment: Is one of those contained in the other?

Comment: kernel of A is contained in the image of B?

Comment: For any $x\in\Bbb R^p$, $A(Bx)=(AB)x=0$, so $\text{image}(B)\subset\ker(A)$.

Comment: ok so what does $Img(B) \subset ker(A)$ mean here?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10901/discussion-between-mark-and-ted-shifrin)

Answer (score 1):

Each column of $B$ must be "orthogonal" to each row of $A$.  If the (row) rank of $A$ is $r \le n$, then the (column) rank of $B$ is at most $n-r$, the dimension of the orthogonal complement of the row span of $A$.